# Running Windows Service on Azure VM with managed identity

Tags: virtual-machine, azure-security

When creating virtual machines, there is an option to create a managed identity for the machine for authenticating to other Azure resources such as storage accounts as referenced in the following Microsoft documentation.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/

I have a virtual machine that runs IIS FTP service.  I'd like to run the windows service as the managed identity so that it can access the storage account used for the ftp root directory, but I can't find a way to successfully specify this managed identity principle under the "This Account" area of the Log On tab of the service.

Is it possible to run a windows service within an Azure VM using the managed identity of the VM assuming the system assigned managed identity has been turned on?  If so, when running the service as a specific user, do you format it like you would a regular managed service account by appending the $ at the end with no password?

Comment: Were you ever able to run the Windows Service with the managed identity of the VM?